# Is probability for double crossing over included in distance cM? [task]

Tags: genetics, homework

We got this task:

There are 3 genes (acb) on one chromosome (linked inheritance). Distance a-c = 12cM, a-b=16cM. Probability for double crossing-over (*CO*) is 0,6%. Find ratio of genotypes of descendants (AcB/acb X acb/acb).

I don't know whether the 0,6% for double *CO* is included in the 16% (16cM) probability.

I think it is not, so I got these ratios:
No *CO* and double *CO*: 42% AcB/acb, 42% acb/acb,
1x *CO*: 8% Acb/acb, 8% acB/acb

Answer (score 1):

Centi-Morgan (cM) is based on observation not precise measurements. Now since double crossing-overs (and actually any arbitrary even number of crossing-overs) revert gene combination to the parental type, resulting lower recombinant frequency. So in your case since the chance (or the frequency if you wish) for double COs is 0.6%, you have to subtract this from parental genotypes and add it to the recombinants.